# Error loading image in the DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

I am trying to load data from the database and display it in the DataGridView, I can display the text just fine but when I try to load an image I get an error. My code is

```
private void LoadData()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connectionManager.connectionString))
            {
                try
                {
                    //MySqlDataAdapter _adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `Mobile`, `Course`, `Gender` FROM student_img", conn);
                    MySqlDataAdapter _adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT `ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Email`, `Mobile`, `Course`, `Gender` , `Image` FROM student_img", conn);

                    DataSet _dataset = new DataSet();
                    _adapter.Fill(_dataset, "table");
                    dataGridViewStudent.DataSource = _dataset;
                    dataGridViewStudent.DataMember = "table";
                    lblRecords.Text = dataGridViewStudent.Rows.Count.ToString();
                    DataGridViewImageColumn Image = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
                    Image = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridViewStudent.Columns[7];
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Error!\n" + ex.Message, "Error Message",
                            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }

        }
```

The error messages I get is

[image]

Comment: looks like the image column cant be converted?  what data type is it in the DB?

Comment: @Plutonix The data type is BLOB in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two lines make no sense:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn Image = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
Image = (DataGridViewImageColumn)dataGridViewStudent.Columns[7];
```

If your columns are being auto-generated the image column will be generated as such and work without further code. This is the simplest way.

And since you don't create any other columns that seems to be what you are doing. So what shall those lines achieve??

Especially as you don't add the extra column anywhere? (Which btw you can't do anyway, as it is already part of the columns collection..)

If you create your dgv columns in code you will have to give each the correct type and connect each one to the right datasource column and add them to the DGV:

```
    string sql = "Select preview, text from Covers;";
    ..
    ..
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);

    // either simply set this to true or..
    dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    // add all columns.. 
    DataGridViewImageColumn dvgic = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
    // setting their names
    dvgic.Name = "preview";
    dvgic.HeaderText = "Preview";
    // and relating them to the data source fields..
    dvgic.DataPropertyName = "preview";
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dvgic);

    dataGridView1.Columns.Add("text", "Text");
    dataGridView1.Columns["text"].DataPropertyName = "text";

    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

If for some reason you need to set an `ImageColumn` cell to an `Image`, be it from whatever source, including a db field that is feeding into a memorystream, then you will have to set the `Value`  of the cell, not the cell itself.

But your error message seems to indicate that at least some of your data are not valid images..